# How to hold the location of an image in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am developing a vb.net winform project that takes a persons photo ID. I want to store the location of the photo in a SQL Server database.

In the project, a persons details are taken (Name, Number, Address, etc) and stored in the database. I can do that part no problem. A photo is taken of the person and stored in a folder on one of the drives on the network. There is an option to choose a photo from this folder in the project and it is added to the profile.

What is the best way to get the location of the image and how do I go about storing it in the Sql server database? I want to be able to use the location of the photo to call it to use again in another part of the project. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why wouldn't you store the full path of the image file?

Comment: Yeah, just store the full path of the image in an varchar/nvarchar field with a suitable length to accommodate the path length

Comment: Thanks lads, I was told on another forum to do exactly that and it works.

Comment: @Coder92, You really need to Google this kind of question rather than posting it on this or any other forum.

Answer (score 0):

In your application, your going to want to use a "OpenFileDialog" so the user can choose the file. See example below:

```vb
Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
ofd.Filter = "*.png|PNG|*.jpg|JPEG" 'Add other exensions you except here
ofd.Title = "Choose your folder"
'ofd.InitialDirectory = "c:\SomeFolder..." 'If you want an initial folder that is shown, otherwise it will use the last folder used by this appliaction in an OFD.
If ofd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    'Something = ofd.FileName 'Do something with the result
End If
```

Then save the result of `ofd.FileName` in your table. This will be the full path and name of the file they selected.