# How to call a file path from a sql server database but not show it?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013

I am using a string to store the file path of an image in a sql server database. I want to call the file path from the database in a vb.net winform project but not show it because I want to just show the image. Can anyone advise me on how to do this? Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:

Just to be clear, the image path is stored as a string in the database from one form, I want to call the path in another form, but I don't want to show the path, I want to show the actual image the path points to.

Comment: guess this is related to your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200102/how-to-hold-the-location-of-an-image-in-a-sql-server-database

Comment: Google this: .net open image from file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a lot of info here, but can you do something like:

```
dim imgReturned as Image

If tblDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then

    imgReturned = Image.FromFile(tblDataTable.Rows(0).Item("ImageFilePathAndName"))

End If
```

Comment: Well, the image path is stored in the database from one form, I want to call the path in another form but I don't want to show the path, I want to show the actual image the path points to.

Comment: Do you get the always path before the second form opens?  Can you pass it into the second forms constructor and use the path to get the image there?

Comment: I used the following line of code that worked:                     pbImage.Image = Image.FromFile(CStr(dtPersons.Rows(0).Item(3)))